# Springdoc specify security as being open

Tags: java, spring, swagger, openapi, springdoc

I'm using Springdoc (`1.4.8`) to document our Rest API.  99% of the calls are secured using an OAuth2 Bearer Token so I'd like to add it by default like this:

```
new OpenAPI()
            .components(new Components()
            .addSecuritySchemes("bearerTokenScheme",
                            new SecurityScheme()
                                    .type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP)
                                    .name("bearerTokenScheme")
                                    .scheme("Bearer")
                                    .bearerFormat("JWT")
                    )
              )
            .addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement()
                    .addList("bearerTokenScheme")
            )
```

This works fine to have it specified by default, but my question is now, can I somehow overrule it by specifying a single call to be unsecured?

I do realize that omitting `.addSecurityItem()` will show calls as unsecured by default, but I'd like to have them secured by default and *only* having to override it when unsecured.

Comment: Override it at the controller level using the `@Operation` annotation.

Comment: @DebarghaRoy Not specifying security attribute at all or specifying it like `@Operation(security = {})` doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and I have solved it using a plugin. The plugin overrides the `security` value of tagged controllers or methods and sets it to empty list. So the tagged endpoints remain unsecured.

```
@Component
public class NoSecurityPlugin implements OpenApiCustomiser {

    private static final List<Function<PathItem, Operation>> OPERATION_GETTERS = Arrays.asList(
            PathItem::getGet, PathItem::getPost, PathItem::getPut, PathItem::getDelete,
            PathItem::getHead, PathItem::getOptions, PathItem::getPatch);

    private static final List<String> tagsForNoSecurity = List.of(
            "public", "unsecured"
    );

    @Override
    public void customise(OpenAPI openApi) {
        openApi.getPaths().forEach((path, item) -> getOperations(item).forEach(api -> {
           List<String> tags = api.getTags();
           if(tags != null && tags.stream().anyMatch(tagsForNoSecurity::contains)) {
               api.setSecurity(Collections.emptyList());
           }
       }));
    }

    private static Stream<Operation> getOperations(PathItem pathItem) {
        return OPERATION_GETTERS.stream()
                .map(g -> g.apply(pathItem))
                .filter(Objects::nonNull);
    }    
}
```

Tag your API methods (or `Controller`):

```
@Tag(name = "public", description = "Public APIs")
```

Comment: Nice approach, but the only drawback I see is that if we have many tags that are public. Is it possible to compare the `Tag`'s description instead of the name?

Comment: @DebarghaRoy Unfortunately the `Operation` class does not provide the tags as a list of `Tags` but `Strings`. Therefore it is not possible to get the tag description.